# BackupPC set blackout on alternate days

Tags: backup, filesystems, backuppc

At the moment my schedule settings look like this.

[image]

How can I only backup to only run on `Mondays(1)` and `Wednesdays(3)`?

What I want to do is alternate between two BackupPC instances so one would backup my share on even and the other one on odd days.

Is this possible?

Comment: Backing up on only some days is reasonable.  But I can't understand why you'd want to run two different instances of BackupPC and have them back up on alternate days.

Comment: The reason is, I want an offsite mirror, but BackupPC doesn't come with this option. I could rsync data from first BackupPC instance or create another instance and let them work on alternate days. In this way, I can still restore data from any of them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a blackout period with hourBegin = 0, hourEnd = 23.99, weekDays = 0, 2, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Well, this are blackout periods, meaning it won't run on these days where I want backups to run only on days specified..

Comment: Look again. That's what this answer does.

Comment: One or more blackout periods can be specified. If a client is subject to blackout then no regular (non-manual) backups will be started during any of these periods. hourBegin and hourEnd specify hours fro midnight and weekDays is a list of days of the week where 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday etc... I imagine in my case backups will only run on weekends and every day between 19.30 and 7.0

Comment: I didn't see you've changed the answer..thanks